# Flask: request.form.getlist won't return any entries

Tags: python, forms, post, flask

for some reason I can't get this thing I worked 4 weeks ago working :/
I have a site where I add a checkbutton via jQuery and I need Flask to read out if it's checked or not.
I made a minmial example, but it still doesn not work.

Heres the code:

**post.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="formular" action='http://127.0.0.1:5000/formtest' method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="test1">
<INPUT type ="submit" id="send" value="Do it"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**webserver.py**

```
@app.route('/formtest', methods=['POST'])
def formtest():
    checklist = request.form.getlist('test1')
    if checklist:
        check = True
    else:
        check = False
    if check:
        return("checked")
    else:
        return("not checked")
```

It always returns "not checked", but I don't get why. Checklist is always an empty list. Where's the error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your checkbox has no `name` attribute; it'll never be sent as part of the POST. Give it a `name` attribute as well as a value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" value="true">
```

Don't use `MultiDict.getlist()` here; you can use [`MultiDict.get()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) with a default and type conversion instead:

```
@app.route('/formtest', methods=['POST'])
def formtest():
    check = request.form.get('test1', default=False, type=bool)
    return 'checked' if check else 'not checked'
```