# request.form.getlist gives an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request, python-requests

My question is similar with [request.form.getlist won't return any entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24204118/6666231) except that I am sending requests within Python. Simplified codes are written below:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/h2ocr", methods=["POST"])
def recognize():  
    report_set = jsonify({"report_set": request.form.getlist("images")})
    return report_set

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=7000)
```

**test_app.py**

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost:7000/h2ocr",
    data=json.dumps({"images": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]})
)
print(json.loads(response.content), response.status_code)
```

`python test_app.py` gives me `{"report_set": []}` and status code 200. How am I supposed to get `{"report_set": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]}` from `response.content`? (Strangely it worked yesterday... :/)

---

**Edits after being marked as duplicated:**

According to [How to get POSTed json in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001229/6666231) and [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/6666231), one can use `json` parameter to pass the json contents with a Python dictionary. However I've already tried that before, I just didn't write it previously:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost:7000/h2ocr",
    data=json.dumps({"images": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]}),
    json={"images": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]},
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
)
print(json.loads(response.content), response.status_code)
```

With any one, any two, or even all of `data`, `json`, `headers` parameters being given in `requests.post`, I am still getting `{"report_set": []}` from `response.content`.

Besides, from the answer of [How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/6666231), I believe that using `request.form.getlist("images")` is correct. What `request.form` is for includes "the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form", and I did send a post request with a key/value pair.

Excuse me but I am not getting help from those suggested duplicates.

Comment: Just try `report_set=request.json`

Comment: @lalithkumar By doing so I am getting `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.